# Lambda expression, shared pointer and the type of this

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, shared-ptr

Consider the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>

struct S: std::enable_shared_from_this<S> {
protected:
    S() = default;

    int bar() { return 42; }
};

struct T: S {
    static std::shared_ptr<T> create() {
        return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T{});
    }

    auto foo() {
        auto ptr = std::static_pointer_cast<T>(shared_from_this());
        return [ptr](){ return ptr->bar(); };
    }

private:
    T() = default;
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<T> ptr = T::create();
    auto lambda = ptr->foo();
    assert(lambda() == 42);
}
```

The code above compiles. It does not if the method `foo` is modified as it follows:

```
auto foo() {
    // In this case, there is no explicit cast
    // The type of ptr is no longer std::shared_ptr<T>
    // It is std::shared_ptr<S> instead 
    auto ptr = shared_from_this();
    return [ptr](){ return ptr->bar(); };
}
```

In this case, the code no longer compiles (neither with GCC nor with clang).

Obviously it would compile after a cast (that is what I did in the first example), but I expected `bar` to be visible to the lambda even in this case, for it is reachable in its context and part of the interface of `S` as well.

I suspect that it is due to [5.1.5p8](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#8), in particular:

> The lambda-expression's compound-statement yields the function-body [...] of the function call operator, but for [...], determining the type and value of *this* [...], the compound-statement is considered in the context of the lambda-expression.

In fact, the error returned by clang is quite clear:

> main.cpp:8:9: note: can only access *this* member on an object of type `T`

Is my deduction right?
Is it due to the mentioned paragraph, thus to a problem of determined type for the `this` pointer that does not match with the one of the shared pointer?

The fact that a `shared_ptr` takes its part in the game makes it a bit harder to me to understand.
Honestly, I'd expect both the examples would compile or both would fail.

Comment: Your `static_pointer_cast` disappeared. Also, does `return [ptr = shared_from_this()](){ return ptr->bar(); };` behave differently?

Comment: `shared_from_this` returns a shared pointer for `S` that is no longer cast to a one for `T`. So actually the type of `ptr` in the second example is `std::shared_ptr<S>`. Do you want me to write it in a more readable way?

Comment: [Works for me](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/hl00GHSN4JZ1Qhi1) after some simple modifications.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's obvious that it compiles that way!! I strongly suspect I failed to explain the issue. Question updated. Forgive me if I've not been clear enough.

Comment: Yes please. I'm not sure what's unclear. You cannot access protected members of other classes ([demo](http://ideone.com/QKq1wi)), so `ptr->bar()` is not accessible in `T` if `ptr` is a pointer to `S`.

Comment: `S::bar` is protected. The lambda in `T::foo` is able access `S::bar` via a _`T*`_ because it's defined in a `T` member function, but this does not give it magical access via a _`S*`_. Then in your code lacking `static_pointer_cast`, you're attempting to call `S::foo` via a `S*`, which was of course just established as not possible.

Comment: @KerrekSB Please, forgive me, the problem of a non native, pretty bad speaker. Actually, the `this` is the same in both the examples, even if its type is different. Should `bar` be accessible anyway?

Comment: @skypjack: `*this` has type `T`, and you can only access protected members of `T`'s bases *of objects of type `T`*. You can however *not* access protected members of objects of *other* types, even though those types may happen to also be bases of `T`. (AnT's answer demonstrates this point.) This doesn't really have anything to do with lambdas and shared pointers.

Comment: @KerrekSB You are right, the presence of a lambda and the shared pointer made me completely miss it. So simple an issue, sorry. Thank you indeed, shame on me for not have seen it immediately. :-)

Comment: No problem. It's always worth checking your basic assumptions on simple examples and building up towards your original problem. That way you can narrow down where the misunderstanding lies.

Comment: @KerrekSB Right. It would also worth thinking about those _issues_ in the morning, instead of opening a question on SO in the evening. I'd probably see the real _issue_ (that is _me_) immediately!! :-) ... Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are simply violating the basic rules of protected access. I.e. the whole thing has nothing to do with lambdas or shared pointers. The good-old rules of protected access that have been around since the beginning of times say that protected members of base class are only accessible through objects of derived class. Contrary to what you stated above, in your context protected members of `S` are not accessible through objects of type `S`, but they are accessible through objects of type `T`.

The whole thing can be reduced the the following simple example

```
struct S
{
protected:
  int i;
};

struct T : S
{
    void foo()
    {
        this->i = 5; // OK, access through `T`

        T t;
        t.i = 5; // OK, access through `T`

        S s;
        s.i = 5; // ERROR: access through `S`, inaccessible

        S *ps = this;
        ps->i = 5; // ERROR: access through `S`, inaccessible
    }
};
```

Comment: It would be more like `S *s = this; s->i = 5;` and, well... you are right. Pretty simple indeed, the lambda made me miserly fail.

Answer (score 3):

I think the comments in the questions have the answer, and I'm not looking to claim credit here.

I thought you might be interested in a 'nicer' way of performing the static cast's job without actually invoking a static cast or even needing to know the base class:

first define this useful free function:

```
template<class T>
auto shared_from_that(T* p)
{
  return std::shared_ptr<T>(p->shared_from_this(), p);
}
```

Then get your correctly typed shared pointer in terms of it:

```
auto foo() {
    return [ptr = shared_from_that(this)](){ 
      return ptr->bar(); 
    };
}
```

Synopsis:

Invokes the (seemingly widely unknown) 2-argument constructor of `std::shared_ptr` which uses the control block from the shared_ptr in arg1 and the pointer to the controlled object in arg2.

Comment: You still deserve credits for the nice trick indeed. Thank you. Is this somehow _better_ (beside the opinion-based answers, I mean in terms of performance or whatever) than using the static cast or it's simply another way of doing it?

Comment: @skypjack it's probably no better or worse than a `static_pointer_cast` in terms of performance, but it requires less maintenance because (a) you don't need to know the type of your class [therefore fewer mistakes during refactoring] and (b) it follows `const`ness correctly automatically.